# sql statement with error

Tags: sql, oracle

i am getting errror but what's the problem. plz help me to so solve this.

```
 select Train_name from TRAIN where Train_id in 
(select Train_id from ROUTE where source_distance in (select source_distance from ROUTE         where stop_number in 
  (select Station_id from STATION where Station_name='Kulaura Railway Station'))  <   source_distance in
      (select source_distance from ROUTE where stop_number in 
          (select Station_id from STATION where Station_name='Saistagonj Railway Station')));
```

**Error:**

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis 
*Cause: 00907. 00000 - "missing right parenthesis" 
*Action: Error at Line: 73 Column: 87
```

Comment: Whats the error you're getting?

Comment: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 73 Column: 87 @Kris Gruttemeyer

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `<` sign - what are you comparing? And why are you using subqueries instead of joins?

Comment: i am new to sql. i think if i use join then it will do more work then using subqueries. i dont know whether i am right or wrong.. @Alex

Comment: Joins are preferable. Not sure it always makes a performance difference but it's easier for the optimiser, and they are much easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Extra `)` and `<`.

Try this

```
SELECT train_name 
FROM   train 
WHERE  train_id IN (SELECT train_id 
                    FROM   route 
                    WHERE  source_distance IN (SELECT source_distance 
                                               FROM   route 
                                               WHERE 
                           stop_number IN (SELECT station_id 
                                           FROM   station 
                                           WHERE 
                           station_name = 'Kulaura Railway Station') AND 
                                   source_distance IN (SELECT source_distance 
                                                       FROM   route 
                                                       WHERE 
                                   stop_number IN (SELECT station_id 
                                                   FROM   station 
                                                   WHERE 
                                   station_name = 'Saistagonj Railway Station')) 
                   );
```

Instead of `SubQuery` You can use `JOIN`

In most cases `JOIN`s are faster than sub-queries and it is very rare for a sub-query to be faster.

In `JOIN`s RDBMS can create an execution plan that is better for your query and can predict what data should be loaded to be processed and save time, unlike the sub-query where it will run all the queries and load all their data to do the processing.

The good thing in sub-queries is that they are more readable than `JOIN`s: that's why most new SQL people prefer them; it is the easy way; but when it comes to performance, JOINS are better in most cases even though they are not hard to read too.

```
SELECT T.train_name  
FROM train T JOIN route R ON R.train_id = T.train_id 
             JOIN station St On St.station_id = R.stop_number
WHERE St.station_name = 'Kulaura Railway Station' OR St.station_name = 'Saistagonj Railway Station'
```

Comment: i am new to sql. i think if i use join then it will do more work then using subqueries. i dont know whether i am right or wrong..which is preferable join or subqueries.

Comment: Join would be better always

Comment: @user3751576 why are you using < symbol there